# Netbeans application 9 using maven

Tags: java, maven, netbeans-platform, netbeans-9

I have downloaded Netbeans 9 sources from github and built it.

Now I would like to create Netbeans application as maven project using api 9, but in project wizard I can only choose between api version 8.2 and 8.1

How to register api version 9 to be able to choose it in project wizard?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the reason is that at this point (end of August 2018) the Netbeans 9.0 artifacts cannot yet be publicly released to a Maven repository, due to ownership of the `org.netbeans` namespace (including the Maven `groupId`) not yet being transferred from Oracle to the Apache Foundation. But it is [in the works](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/netbeans-dev/201808.mbox/%3CCACkjAxTdtCZSmUECmJ9SJ78eifTwO5VNX7ExCYEE_zOXW80apw%40mail.gmail.com%3E).